# FilterExpression Does Not Work? Why?

Tags: objectdatasource

ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "userid LIKE '{0}' AND action LIKE '{1}'";
    ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("userid", ddlUsers.SelectedValue);
    ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("action", ddlAction.SelectedValue);

I wirte like this code.

when I run it grid view is empty. BUT, when I write and run it works good.

```
ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "userid LIKE '{0}' AND action LIKE '{Login}'";
ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("userid", ddlUsers.SelectedValue);
ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("action", ddlAction.SelectedValue);
```

Without parameters (action)
its shows all login of selected ddlUsers.SelectedValue.

Why does not work like this?

```
ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = "userid LIKE '{0}' AND action LIKE '{1}'";
ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("userid", ddlUsers.SelectedValue);
ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("action", ddlAction.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes :) I found the problem.

Before this code, I used ObjectDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add("userid", Name); code
so 3 filterParameters.

So this query is empty. Grid View shows empty information.
I remove all parameters and I add just this two parameters and it's ok. It shows very good.

:)